# How do I create popover with a javascript view and a controller no html

Tags: javascript, sapui5, popover

so at the minute I have a view that looks something like this.

```
                var oPopOver = new sap.m.Link({
                text:"PopOver",
                press : function() {
                    oController.getPopOver()
                },
                    }).addStyleClass("PopOver");
```

Then I'd assume in the controller I'd have something similiar to this:

```
    getPopOver: function(oEvent) {

    $(function () {
        $('#example').popover();
    });
}
```

I just dont understand where all the popover stuff goes I've previously worked with Java and I am a SAP ABAP Developer but this is our first SAP UI5 project which means we need to do some web development using javascript etc. So any help with this would be great I been following tutorials fine but they all seem to show putting the popover information in the html tags etc.

Comment: See the example on https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Popover/preview - The popover content usually goes into a separate fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sap.m.Popover`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Popover.html#constructor)

*JS view*

```
 var link = new sap.m.Link("link", {
     text: "Click for Popover",
     press: function() {
         oController.handleLinkPress()
     },
 })
```

*controller*

```
 handleLinkPress: function(e) {
     var link = this.getView().byId("link");
     var oPopover = new sap.m.Popover({
         title: "Sample Popover",
         content: [new sap.m.Image({
             src: "https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png",
             width: "150px"
         })],
         footer: [new sap.m.Button({
             text: "Click me!"
         })]
     });
     oPopover.openBy(link);
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/reziba/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Hey I tried this but I'm getting the error "Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate object: "new" is missing! " any ideas? But if this code does work it, looks very simple and will work perfectly.

Comment: yer I tried that, I dont seem to be getting any error in the console but also cant seem to see the pop over. it definitely get in to the controller function as I placed a breakpoint there and it reaches the breakpoint on click. May i be missing an API now?

Comment: I'm trying to get a popup on click. Which I think this does (from viewing the demo on the website). But with the code I see on the click it gets in to controller function but it doesn't actually execute the pop up on the web page. Could I be missing a UI5 class/API for the popover ?

Comment: `sap.m.Popover` does not require any class to be imported unless you are under any other namespace than `sap.m`. I can only help you ahead if you could share your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117326/discussion-between-j0rd4n500-and-dopedev).